# PowerShell get user, groups from server

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script which gets all the users and Groups data from a Windows Server. But this script has to be run on each server because I don't find a `-ComputerName` option to run in different servers. So that script has to be modified and when we run the script from one server based on the servers list input it should get all the data from Windows servers.

Comment: is there a question that you want to ask? [*grin*] also, what script are you talking about ... i don't see one in your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a script the does this even for 1 computer, you can do it for as many computers as you choose using a ForEach.

```
'computer1',computer2','computer3' | 
ForEach {
    # put your code here 
    # and for the computername property, use $PSItem to get the name being passed in
}
```

You can get the current computer name of where the code is being ran, simply by asking for it using the environment variable

```
$env:COMPUTERNAME
```

Or just using

```
hostname
```

What you are not doing is showing us your code, so we have no idea what you are doing.
Many of the cmdlets / WMI and CIM classes have a computer name parameter, so, if you are not seeing it, then you are not using a cmdlet/function that does.

This also indicates that you would be very new to PowerShell, and I'd recommend you spend the time getting ramped up. Use YouTube, MSDN Channe9 or MS Learn resources and search for ...

- 'Beginning PowerShell'
- 'Intermediate PowerShell'
- 'Advanced Powershell'
- 'PowerShell running commands remote computer'

Always use the help files first.

```
Get-Command -Name '*Computer*' | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Results

CommandType Name                                        Version      Source                                              
----------- ----                                        -------      ------                                                                                
Cmdlet      Add-ADComputerServiceAccount                1.0.1.0      ActiveDirectory                                     
Cmdlet      Add-Computer                                3.1.0.0      Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                     
Cmdlet      Add-WsusComputer                            2.0.0.0      UpdateServices                                      
Cmdlet      Checkpoint-Computer                         3.1.0.0      Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                     
Cmdlet      Disable-ComputerRestore                     3.1.0.0      Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                     
Cmdlet      Enable-ComputerRestore                      3.1.0.0      Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                     
Cmdlet      Get-ADComputer                              1.0.1.0      ActiveDirectory                                     
Cmdlet      Get-ADComputerServiceAccount                1.0.1.0      ActiveDirectory                                     
Cmdlet      Get-ComputerInfo                            3.1.0.0      Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                     
Cmdlet      Get-ComputerRestorePoint                    3.1.0.0      Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                     
Cmdlet      Get-WsusComputer                            2.0.0.0      UpdateServices                                      
Cmdlet      New-ADComputer                              1.0.1.0      ActiveDirectory                                     
..                       
Cmdlet      Remove-ADComputer                           1.0.1.0      ActiveDirectory                                     
Cmdlet      Remove-ADComputerServiceAccount             1.0.1.0      ActiveDirectory                                     
Cmdlet      Remove-Computer                             3.1.0.0      Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                     
Cmdlet      Rename-Computer                             3.1.0.0      Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                     
Cmdlet      Reset-ComputerMachinePassword               3.1.0.0      Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                     
Cmdlet      Restart-Computer                            3.1.0.0      Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                     
Cmdlet      Restore-Computer                            3.1.0.0      Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                     
Cmdlet      Set-ADComputer                              1.0.1.0      ActiveDirectory                                     
Cmdlet      Stop-Computer                               3.1.0.0      Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                     
Cmdlet      Test-ComputerSecureChannel                  3.1.0.0      Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                     


# Find all cmdlets / functions with a target parameter
# Ignore any error show, as that just means the object does not have it
Get-Command -CommandType Function | 
Where-Object { $_.parameters.keys -match 'computer'} | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available functions which has a specific parameter'

Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet | 
Where-Object { $_.parameters.keys -match 'computer'}| 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Results for cmdlets which has a specific parameter'

# Results (truncated for brevity)

CommandType     Name                 Version    Source
-----------     ----                 -------    ------
Cmdlet          Add-Computer         3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     
Cmdlet          Connect-PSSession    3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Core           
Cmdlet          Connect-WSMan        3.0.0.0    Microsoft.WSMan.Management          
Cmdlet          Disconnect-WSMan     3.0.0.0    Microsoft.WSMan.Management          
Cmdlet          Enter-PSSession      3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Core           
Cmdlet          Get-CimInstance      1.0.0.0    CimCmdlets                          
Cmdlet          Get-Process          3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     
Cmdlet          Get-EventLog         3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     
Cmdlet          Get-Service          3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     
Cmdlet          Get-WmiObject        3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     
Cmdlet          Invoke-CimMethod     1.0.0.0    CimCmdlets                          
Cmdlet          Invoke-Command       3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Core           
Cmdlet          Invoke-WmiMethod     3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     
Cmdlet          Stop-Computer        3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     
Cmdlet          Test-Connection      3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management

...



# get function / cmdlet details
Get-Command -Name Get-CimInstance -Syntax

(Get-Command -Name Get-WMIObject).Parameters.Keys

 # Results
...
 Credential
 ThrottleLimit
 ComputerName
 Namespace
...

(Get-Command -Name Get-CimInstance).Parameters.Keys

# Results

CimSession
ClassName
...
ComputerName
...
Property
...

Get-help -Name Get-CimInstance -Full
Get-help -Name Get-CimInstance -Online
Get-help -Name Get-CimInstance -Examples

Examples:

...
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName Server01,Server02
...
$s = New-CimSession –ComputerName Server01,Server02
...
```